Is it possible to create Lockfile from R Project library?
Is it possible to create a lockfile (and then restore previous package versions) in R from an R project library? Something has gone wrong with my use of renv (I believe I was installing packages into the project library, after using renv::init(), but never took a snapshot. Now I have these packages in the project library directory (~\renv\library\R-4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\renv), but my lockfile is basically empty save for renv. To make matters worse, somehow I updated R to 4.4 and so I have two directories in the renv library project directory. My code has broken and so I'm trying to revert to the state with the versions of the packages in the 4.3 project renv library.
